# ASP.NET invalid script resource request instead of redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, global-asax

Several bots/crawlers are scanning our websites, and I'm wondering if there is something I can change that when a page cannot be found (for example: www.mysite.com/scriptresource.axd)
it will be redirected to a page instead of displaying the error:

```
Message:
This is an invalid script resource request.
```

I've configured the `global.asax` that I will receive mail on errors, but I'm receiving tons of those emails that a bot has been trying to access a non-existing page. `e.g. ScriptResource.axd`

Please take note of the following:

- You need to login before you can do anything on the website, but the bot will cause this error somehow.
- If you're logged in and try to reach a non existing page you end up
  with a manual 404 (RemoteOnly) error.
- In the Global.asax I've added a check on Session_start for IP's that they will be redirected to Google. However, they can still cause this error.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you perfectly, you can do such as below:

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim ctx As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current
    Dim file_ext As String = ctx.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension

    If file_ext = ".axd" Then
        ctx.Response.Redirect("http://bing.com")
    Else
        ' email error detail
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is no way to redirect via the error page :) I'm trying Application_BeginRequest instead of Session_Start now. Thanks though.